# Can't make the button looks correct

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Now I read the book "*ASP.NET MVC5, Freeman*" and I have create a web-site.
Here how it looks like:

[image]

Button **Home** must looks like another button, I can't understand, what's wrong.
I am new in the ASP.NET, so I don't know, whe to look for the error.

Here is structure of my project:

- SportsStore.Domain - for logic
- SportsStore.UnitTests - for tests
- SportsStore.WebUI - for views and controllers

[image]

I think, that problem is somevhere in the SportsStore.WebUI.

**Menu.schtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product", null,
                     new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-defautl btn-lg" })
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
    {
        controller = "Product",
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    }, new
   {
        @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
            + (link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? " btn-primary" : "")
    })
}
```

**List.cshtml**

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Products )
{
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List",
        new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
</div>
```

**Edit1 - Generated HTML-code**

```
<html><div id="coFrameDiv" style="height:0px;display:none;"><iframe id="coToolbarFrame" src="chrome-extension://cjabmdjcfcfdmffimndhafhblfmpjdpe/toolbar/placeholder.html" style="height: 0px; width: 100%; display: none;"></iframe></div><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Products</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="coToolbarStyle" href="chrome-extension://cjabmdjcfcfdmffimndhafhblfmpjdpe/toolbar/styles/placeholder.css" type="text/css"><script type="text/javascript" id="cosymantecbfw_removeToolbar">(function () {             var toolbarElement = {},                    parent = {},                    interval = 0,                   retryCount = 0,                 isRemoved = false;              if (window.location.protocol === 'file:') {                 interval = window.setInterval(function () {                     toolbarElement = document.getElementById('coFrameDiv');                     if (toolbarElement) {                           parent = toolbarElement.parentNode;                         if (parent) {                               parent.removeChild(toolbarElement);                             isRemoved = true;                               if (document.body && document.body.style) {                                 document.body.style.setProperty('margin-top', '0px', 'important');                              }                           }                       }                       retryCount += 1;                        if (retryCount > 10 || isRemoved) {                         window.clearInterval(interval);                     }                   }, 10);             }           })();</script></head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-defautl btn-lg" href="/">Home</a>
<a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" href="/Chess">Chess</a><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" href="/Soccer">Soccer</a><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" href="/Watersports">Watersports</a>;
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">


<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>Kayak</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">275,00 ₽</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">A boat for one person</span>
</div><div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>Lifejacket</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">48,95 ₽</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">Protective and fascionable</span>
</div><div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>Soccre ball</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">19,50 ₽</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">FIFA-approver size and weight</span>
</div><div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>Corner Flags</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">34,95 ₽</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">Give you playing field a professional touch</span>
</div>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-primary selected" href="/">1</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Page2">2</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Page3">3</a>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"71da9908a09f40e490a8f3c96abdeaaa"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:60023/6e11616ea0ef4c01be4ca7cc7741a6e8/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->


</body></html>
```

Maybe it will help:
https://github.com/dmitrykozyr/SportsStoreMVC

**Using categories - part of the file _Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
            @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav");
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like your `btn-primary` CSS rule hides the border.

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML code?

Comment: @ChrFin If you mean code, which I can see by presssing F12 in the browser, then it is in the edit1

Comment: Yes - nothing wrong there. Do you have anything `#categories` related in your CSS/LESS/SASS?

Comment: Are you new to ASP.NET MVC or new to web development in general? The ASP.NET part is irrelevant, this issue is purely caused by CSS. Inspect the button in your browser's developer tools so you can see the applied CSS styles, and compare it to the button below it. Then you know what CSS to change.

Comment: I think you misspelled `btn-defautl` in your "Home"-link, or is that just a typo?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that was error, thanks a lot. So easy.. You can post it as answer and I'll mark it

Comment: np, it's often the small things we miss :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your Home-link, you have misspelled default

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product", null,
                 new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-defautl btn-lg" })
```

should be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product", null,
                 new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" })
```